# PHP replace part of string with link based on pattern

Tags: php, string, replace, substring

I would like to replace all words starting with 3ABC with an link including the found word. For example:

> teststring 3ABCJOEDKLSZ2 teststring hello test

Output would be:

```
test string <a href='https://google.com/search/3ABCJOEDKLSZ2'>3ABCJOEDKLSZ2</a>  teststring hello test
```

The substring I am looking for is always starting with 3ABC everything after that is dynamic.

Comment: Standard counter question for such kind of request: what have you tried so far?

Comment: `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: `3ABC\S+` or `3ABC[a-zA-Z\D]+`  I think would do it... or if `3abc` also is valid make the `+` a `*`. Hard to tell where your `preg_replace` went wrong without the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use php's [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function to match 3ABC followed by 0 or more characters that is not whitespace and then use the match in your code:

```
$literal = "teststring 3ABCJOEDKLSZ2 teststring hello test";
$formatted = preg_replace("/3ABC\S*/", '<a href="https://google.com/search/\0">\0</a>', $literal);

echo $formatted;
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/C0PWM)

Comment: As simple as it looks, I couldn't find the right replace formule. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function makeLink($string)
{
    $pattern='/^3ABC[\w\d]+$/';
    $url='https://google.com/search/';
    $result=preg_replace($pattern, $url.$string ,$string);
    return $result;
}
echo makeLink('3ABCHJDGIFD');
?>
```

Like this?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

the pattern will match any digit or word character after 3ABC.